# Docker swarm don't publish ports

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have an error whith docker swarm new services when I'm added somes services with a port like :

```
docker service create --name=elasticSearch  --network=swarm-net -e xpack.security.enabled=false -e xpack.monitoring.enabled=false -e xpack.graph.enabled=false -e xpack.watcher.enabled=false -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -d docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.2
```

When I don't publish any ports the service works well but when I'm added it, the process stay at state "new" not running.

Did you have an idea ?

Regards

Comment: Is the published port available on all nodes in your swarm?

Comment: Yes it is. I have check with netstat.

Comment: How many managers and how many nodes?

Comment: The command is perfect. So you need to debug now. `journalctl -n10 -f` in one terminal and execute the command in another terminal and see if you can find the issues